# $b^{n-1} \equiv 1$ $mod$ $n$ implies gcd($b$,$n$) = $1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to prove that if $b^{n-1} \equiv 1 \pmod n$ then $\mathrm{gcd}(b,n) = 1$ as long as $n > 1$.

I believe this to be true and think its connected to Fermat's Little Theorem somehow, but I can't see how to prove it.

Comment: If $b^k \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ for *any* $k$, then $b$ is a unit of $\Bbb Z/ n \Bbb Z$ so it can't be a zero divisor (in the ring) and therefore must be relatively prime to $n$.

Comment: Also true for $n = 1$. :P

Answer (score 2):

Hint:$$b^{n-1}\equiv 1\bmod n\iff \exists v\in\mathbb{Z}, b\times b^{n-2}+v\times n=1$$

Comment: This proof is a special case of a proof of a general correspondence between divisibility mod $n$ and divisibility of integers - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $b^{n-1} \equiv 1(modn) \Rightarrow  b^{n-1} -1 = kn$  for some integer $k$ and so $b^{n-1}-kn=1$. We know $b^{n-1}=b \cdot b^{n-2}$ which means that $b \cdot b^{n-2} -kn =1$. Since $b$ and $n$ can be written as a linear combination equal to $1$, the gcd$(b,n)=1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is the special case $\ a = 1\ $ of  $\,(\Rightarrow)\,$ below. $\ $  Here $\ x\mid y\ $ means $\,x\,$ divides $\,y$.

$\!\begin{align}{\bf Lemma}\qquad\quad\   b\mid a\,\ {\rm in}\,\ \Bbb Z_{\large n}&\iff \gcd(b,n)\mid a\,\ {\rm in}\,\ \Bbb Z\\[.3em]
{\bf Proof}\ \ \  \exists\, x,y\!:\ nx\! +\! by = a&\iff  \gcd(b,n)\mid a\ \ \rm by\  Bezout\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $gcd(b,n)=d\neq 1$. In one hand since $d|b$ you have $b^{n-1}=0 \mod d$. But on the other hand, from  $b^{n-1}=1 \mod n$ and $d|n$, we get  $b^{n-1}=1 \mod d$. A contradiction mod $d$